# Adding tabs to the Experience Profile overview

Tags: experience-profile

I'm using sitecore9.0.1, i used the xprofile to save custom Events in the "interactions" table in DB by defining the custom models and triggering the related page event on a certain action that the user performs. 
I know that "Experience Profile" tab in the launchpad is used to view all interactions made by the user, when i view it i can see it also shows my custom events in the "overview" tab.
[image]
 However it only shows the name of my events but my question is :
Is there a way to add an extra tab in which i can view the properties i saved in those custom events (for example: the page event name, the time,the page title,......) and to also generate custom reports for those custom events ??

Comment: I use this and it works great, but we need to upgrade it to Sitecore 9. https://github.com/JeffDarchuk/EPExpressTab

Comment: Would this help: https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2018/02/displaying-extra-data-on-sitecore-9-goal.html? It's a solution to display extra goal (or event) data in the activity tab (so not an extra tab).  Can elaborate in an answer if it covers your needs..

Comment: @ Gatogordo  yes, this could be very helpful. would you please elaborate more?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @ Chris Auer Thanks alot for this solution, i tried it and it worked. I have another question please. Do you have any clue how can i add tables and navigation tabs inside this new tab? I want to add tables that have the same layout as the default tabs

Comment: Amira, please take some time to familiarise yourself with the nature of this site. Asking additional questions; raising same questions multiple times; thanking people in comments but not upvoting their answers or marking them correct - all of this indicates that you would be doing yourself and this community a favour by reading up a bit. Come find us on Slack if you need further explanation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because explained in comment